# Magento Only show products with image on home page

Tags: php, image, magento

I`m working with random products on my homepage and i`m trying to show only products with images and in stock. I managed to get it to show only products with image and instock by using the code below:

```
<?php
 $products_noimage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'));     
 ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php  if(!$_product->isSaleable() && $products_noimage && $_product->isInStock())continue; ?>
<?php //if criteria is meet show products below     
?>
```

but my problem is when homepage is loaded sometimes it will show only 1 or 2 products in the grid since I have lots of products without image and outofstock I think the page is loading products outofstock and without image but showing only 1 or 2 products with image and in stocky.

Example: the page will load 16 products in the grid from those 16 products only 2 have image and are instock the rest do not meet this criteria..

How to avoid it and instead of loading only those 2 that meet the criteria load in sequence the others products that meed those criteria (with image and instock)..

or maybe it will never work because i`m using the list.phtml block ?

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random"        template="catalog/product/productrandomhom.phtml"}}
```

If anyone has a solution to filter random products on home page feel to share =)

Answer (score 0):

your  logic is something wrong

First copy Random.php from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List` 
to  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List`

then goto function and image filter `in _getProductCollection()`

change from  `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');`
to

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'));
```

,you are  showing only salable product and ins tock

> if($_product->isSaleable() && $_product->isInStock()==1){ }else{
>   continue; }

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

`<?php`

`$products_noimage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'));

 ?>`

`<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>`
`<?php  if(!$_product->isSaleable() && $_product->isInStock()==0)continue; ?>
          //if criteria is meet show products below
?>`